# sql filter many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables

```
competitions
id prize
1 win a car
2 win an ipod

competition_type
competition_id Type_id
  1              1
  1              2
  2              1

Type
id   type
1    facebook
2    twitter
```

How can i select all the competitions that are facebook but NOT twitter. So i should get Win an ipod as the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ct.competition_id FROM
    competitions c
JOIN competition_type ct ON ct.competition_id = c.id AND ct.Type_id = 1 
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM competitions c2 
                     JOIN competition_type ct2 
                     ON ct2.competition_id = c2.id AND ct2.Type_id = 2 
                     WHERE c2.id = c.id)
```

Comment: i think this is on the right track.. i only posted a simple version of what i have.. ill try this.. Many competition types can be included and many excluded

Comment: Yay. this works, i replaced the * with c2.id, I'm guessing that would make it faster?

Comment: @Alessandro : This is a correct answer. Yet do know that most the of the answer do the job for you except one. And it's a matter of which column you want to ouput :) If you are use this query you have to provide compeition IDs. All the other correct answers only need you to provide the main condition whether it's Facebook or Twitter ;) I am not saying this cos I have answered :P

Comment: Can you explain the Where clause? Without it, you get a result set of 1 and 2, because you can win a car and an ipod from facebook. Can't you just specify `Where competition_id = 2` to get the ipod?

Answer (score 1):

How about the query:

```
Select Prize from 
Competitions a inner join competition_type b on a.id=b.competition_id
    inner join Type c on b.Type_id=c.id
Where c.Type='facebook' and c.Type<>'twitter'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
select cmp.id, cmp.prize from 
competitions cmp inner join competition_type ct on cmp.id = ct.competition_id
inner join Type t on t.id = ct.type_id
where t.type = 'facebook'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    competition a
WHERE   a.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT  b.competition_id
    FROM    competition_type b 
            INNER JOIN Type c
                ON b.type_ID = c.id
    WHERE   c.type = 'twitter'
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99549/1)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this example

```
select * from Competitions as c
left join competition_type as ct
on c.id = ct.competition_id
left join Type as t
on t.id = ct.Type_id
where t.Type <> 'Twitter'
;
```

Results:

```
ID  PRIZE         COMPETITION_ID    TYPE_ID     TYPE
1   win a car     1                 1           facebook
2   win an ipod   2                 1           facebook
```

** Updated with <>  `Twitter`

[SQLFIDDLE Reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ded85/5)